# Пустая админка modx

Tags: modx, denwer

Установил систему **modx revo 2.4.2** на локальную машину.  Админка почему-то пустая (Примечание, захожу в раздел */manager/*).

Установка проходила корректно, никаких ошибок не диагностировала. В чем может быть проблема?

Лог денверовский, по поводу работы данной системы дает ошибки:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jan/2016:14:20:03 +0600] "GET /land-pages/manager/ HTTP/1.1" 500 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jan/2016:14:21:00 +0600] "GET /land-pages/\\core/docs/changelog.txt HTTP/1.1" 206 1
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jan/2016:14:20:58 +0600] "GET /land-pages/manager/ HTTP/1.1" 500 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jan/2016:14:21:01 +0600] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 318
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jan/2016:14:22:43 +0600] "GET /land-pages/\\core/docs/changelog.txt HTTP/1.1" 206 1
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jan/2016:14:22:41 +0600] "GET /land-pages/manager/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jan/2016:14:22:44 +0600] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 318
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jan/2016:14:23:45 +0600] "GET /land-pages/\\core/docs/changelog.txt HTTP/1.1" 206 1
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jan/2016:14:23:43 +0600] "GET /land-pages/manager/ HTTP/1.1" 500 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jan/2016:14:23:46 +0600] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 318
```

**500** - ошибка сервера, насколько я помню. 
**200** - ошибка тоже выскакивает, судя по логам. Такая проблема была давно, когда изучать только начал модекс.

В качестве устранения неполадок, предпринял такие действия:

1) Прописал: строку `'compress_js' => '1'`, меняем на `'compress_js' => '0'`,
строку `'compress_css' => '1'`, меняем на `'compress_css' => '0'`, в файле `/core/cache/system_settings/config.cache.php`

2) В папке `/manager/.htaccess` прописал:

```
php_value suhosin.get.max_value_length 4096
```

3) И, наконец, третья попытка устранить проблему. Акселератор изменен таким образом:

```
php_value eaccelerator.enable 0
```

В папке `/manager/min/.htaccess`

Тем не менее, все эти мероприятия не смогли исправить проблему. Потому жду советов от людей, которые давно уже с этим работали. Потому я начинаю грешить уже мыслями про ошибки в `CGI`. Файлы доступа `.htaccess` настроил, как указано было вышел. Глобальные переменные отключил. Что не так делаю?

Comment: Нужны логи, иначе просто пальцем в небо.. Почитай еще эту статейку  https://habrahabr.ru/post/151508/  может поможет

Comment: @МихаилЛуцко, спасибо за совет. Статью смотрел. В курсе этих операций, однако, все это не помогло к сожалению. Добавил вывод лога в вопрос, чтобы не тыкать пальцем в небо, как говорится).

Comment: @МихаилЛуцко на стороне браузера в консоли что нибудь выводится? если ребята из modx ничего глобального не изменили, то у них элементы в админке грузятся через `iframe`. Проще говоря, могут быть проблемы на стороне `js`

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/486728/%D0%9F%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0-modx-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-denwer/486998#486998