# Пустая админка modx на локальном сервере denwer

Tags: modx, denwer

Сегодня на всех сайтах, находящихся на локальной машине поломалась админка. После авторизации просто белое окно, не выдает ничего. в логах apache:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jan/2016:19:12:41 +0300] "GET /\\core/docs/changelog.txt HTTP/1.1" 206 1
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jan/2016:19:12:40 +0300] "GET /manager/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Странное совпадение, но вот тут [Пустая админка modx](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/486511/%D0%9F%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0-modx/486719#486719) точно такая же проблема. никаких изменений не вносила, modx не обновляла. Есть версии и 2.2 и 2.4. Что за магия, и как решить проблему???

UPD: Проверила на домашнем ноутбуке, все тоже самое. Значит проблема какая-то новая и не локальная. А походу на всех связках denwer+modx. Сегодня буду пробовать другой сервак

Comment: В браузере посмотрите через `dev tools` консоль. Там ничего не выводится?

Comment: @Olegatro, ничего не выводится. просто пустая страница. на домашнем ноутбуке все тоже самое, что позволяет сделать вывод что проблема отнюдь не локальная.

Comment: Попробуйте как тут [советуют](https://modx.ru/vopros-otvet/info/2502/)

Comment: @Olegatro, супер, спасибо. кто бы мог подумать

Comment: @NeedHate рад был помочь, опубликую как отдельное решение.

Answer (score 1):

> После авторизации откройте прямую ссылку: site.ru/manager/?a=system/settings
>   И отключите Отображение RSS-канала «Уведомления безопасности MODX»

[Истончик](https://modx.ru/vopros-otvet/info/2502/)